# An error when I used flutter and I could not solve it for someone who knows it, please write the answer

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to
This error appears to me

Comment: try to restart your IDE and device (uninstall app first). If still not working try to run `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get`

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.